# Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient once installed

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0, sqlclient

If we deploy our .NET 6 WPF application using Dev Ops or I do a publish using Visual Studio my code works as expected.
However, when I add the output of the published files to a Visual Studio install, I also tried using WIX.
Then I get the attached error...
Has anybody got any suggestions?

I have tried using System.Data.SqlClient instead of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, but this just causes another similar error